# Clear multipleselection items in a multiselect combobox in wpf mvvm

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox

I was able to create a multiselect combobox in wpf using http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/563862/Multi-Select-ComboBox-in-WPF.

Now when I have a clear button,the selectedvalues in the combobox need to be cleared,but they are not clearing.

I binded a list to multiselected combobox selecteditems and was trying to clear that when on clear,but items selected were still showing up.Am i mssing anyhting trivial.

Here is the line in my viewmodel where SelectedPractices is the list that has combobox selecteditems:

```
SelectedPractices.Clear();
OnPropertyChanged("SelectedPractices");
```

Please see the xaml code:Basically this is a custom combobox control created using the link given and i used it in the below way.and yes the SelectedPractices implements InotifyProperty.
xaml:

```
  <multiselection:MultiSelectComboBox x:Name="CmbPractice" Grid.Row="1"     ItemsSource="{Binding Practices}" SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedPractices,Mode=TwoWay}" Width="145" Margin="3,4,28,1" Grid.Column="1">
 </multiselection:MultiSelectComboBox>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `SelectedPractices` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`? Is it an `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: Add the XAML and related code behind

Comment: Hi Mike,yes it implements INotifyPropertyChanged and its a list.

Comment: @SriyahKantha Change it to an `ObservableCollection`, the UI will **not** be notified when items are added/removed from a `List`.

Comment: sure.thanks mikwe.i would try that.but was wondering if I jsut do a codebehind line  like CmbPractice.Selecteditems.Clear() should do too right?

Comment: I made it an observablecollection and used SelectedPractices.Clear and in codebehind i added CmbPractice.Text="";It just shows blank but items were still checked.Any ideas please.Thanks

Comment: Because its a custom control and is being used in other page,even if its cleared using SelectedP.Clear(),it didnt clear checkeboxes.So i have made the itemsource of combobox null and then rebinded it.So the cehckbox selections were cleared.Thanks much  Mike and Noam for your time.